# Update counter in Firebase with Angular Fire 2

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am building an app with Ionic 2 and AngularFire 2
I would like to update an object each time a user hits a "vote" button.

Updating a property with a fixed number is no problem with

```
  let userRate = 8
  this.currentBeer = this.af.database.object('/beers/' + scannedText);

  this.currentBeer.update({
    votes: 35,
    total: 642
  })
```

But I want to first get the current "votes" and "total" property, and then increment these values

I tried several options with .subscribe or .forEach methods, but I think the problem is in the async property of an observable?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the $ref possibilities...
Then you can use all the Firebase API

This code did the job for me :

```
  this.currentBeer = this.af.database.object('/beers/' + scannedText);

  this.currentBeer.$ref.once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
      let obj = snapshot.val()
      this.currentBeer.update({
        total: obj.total + userRating,
        votes: obj.votes + 1
      })
  })
```

Comment: FYI, you could also use [`transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction).